# how to filter already retrieved data from firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic2

I have a list of posts under the '/posts/' , I have retrieved all posts and store it in an array all_posts:

```
get_all_posts(){

 this.all_posts = [];
 firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(snapshot => {

 foreach.snapshot{
    let tmp_data = {
        post_id: snapshot.key,
        title: snapshot.val().title,
        type: snapshot.val().type,
        }   
    this.all_posts.push(tmp_data);
 }

}
```

Now I would like to filter the posts of type = "news" (there are 2 types: news and blogs)upon a button click

```
<ion-button (click)="show_only_posts_type_news()">show only news</ion-button>

show_only_posts_types_news(){

 //this.posts
 // filter only type == "news"

}
```

is there a easier way to filter all_posts ? without another firebase query to show only the news type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already looping through the snapshot, it might be better if you do the filtering in that loop rather than looping again through all_posts to get the news, and likely later to get blogs, which what the array.filter does in the background.

```
get_all_posts(){

this.news_posts = [];
this.blogs_posts = [];
firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(snapshot => {

foreach.snapshot{ 
 let tmp_data = {
        post_id: snapshot.key,
        title: snapshot.val().title,
        type: snapshot.val().type,
         }  
  if(tmp_data.type === 'news'
  {
    this.news_posts(tmp_data)
  }
  else
  {
    this.blogs_posts(tmp_data)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks Mocas I figured out a way with array.filter method which I have answered below, but I think grouping the posts during the snapshot seems a better way, as you mentioned I don't have to filter again. thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You can provide a function to filter which will evaluate and return only those elements which satisfy your condition.

```
var news_posts = this.all_posts.filter(post => post.type === 'news')
```

Comment: thanks ashish, for the answer, I now figured out a way to filter the retrieved data (filtering at the time of snapshots) for my current situation it fits,but  your answer is very useful for a more complicated search involving, more parameters. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Ashish (for the Array.filter function, opened many ways of filtering data with this).
@Mocas I will have more types of posts later,your method is also workable.

I ended up doing this , one function that filters the post type  upon the button clicks, not sure if it's the best , but works as intended:

I have assigned 3 arrays first:

```
rows = [];          //the row that contains displaying data on the view
all_rows = [];      //the row that contains all the posts
filtered_rows = []; //the row that contains only filtered posts
```

The filter function:

```
filter_posts_by_type(type){

    this.filtered_rows = this.all_rows; 
    //reset the filtered_rows with all data first

    if(type == "news"){

        this.rows = this.filtered_rows.filter((item) => {
            return item.type.toLowerCase() == "news"; 
            //set this.rows to contain all posts of type : news
        })

    }else if(type == "blog"){ 

        this.rows = this.filtered_rows.filter((item) => {
            return item.type.toLowerCase() == "blog"; 
           //set this.rows to contain all posts of type : blog

        })
    }else{
        // all types
        this.rows = this.filtered_rows.filter((item) => {
            return item.type.toLowerCase() == "news" || item.type.toLowerCase() == "blog"; 
           //set this.rows to contain all posts types
        })
    }
}
```